# Facebook Graph API get all posts on group page

Tags: python, parsing, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's Graph API to get all posts off a group page. I just need the actual comment and datetime to generate a word-map.

Currently I am using:

```
groupData = graph.get("*****/feed", page=True, limit=1)
for data in groupData:
    n=0
    print(data)
    print()
    for item in data["data"]:
        for i in item:
            print(n, i)
            n += 1
        print()
```

which returns:

```
0 id
1 message
2 created_time
```

or sometimes

```
0 message
1 id
2 created_time
```

How would one go about always getting messages constantly or why do the results change from running the same code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using

```
for part in item:
    if part == "message":
        messageFB = item[part]
        print("message: ", messageFB)
    if part == "created_time":
        timeFB = dateparser.parse(item[part]).replace(tzinfo=None)
        print("Time: ", timeFB)
```

where "part" is a refactor of "i" above.